# LiteDB 5 backup while application is running

Tags: litedb

We are using liteDB 5.0 in a desktop application that will run 24 hours a day, 7 days a week, 50 weeks a year.
I wonder what is the best way to make a backup there.
The simplest solution is to back up the database file, but it is open all the time.
I couldn't find a backup function or similar, what are the options?

Comment: https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/issues/1676 seems relevant.